# SQL - Selecting Multi Keyword Values From Single Field

Tags: sql-server

So I'm building a SQL view for more readable data I'll use to report on. I have one table that houses field data (keyword ids) for questions within a section on a website. Column3 is a multi-keyword field and stored in the DB delimited by chr(185).

## Table 1

```
    Column1 | Column2 | Column3
       4456 |    2323 | ¹8661¹8662¹
```

I have a second table that houses keyword ids and their values.

## Table 2

```
  Column1  | Column2
     4456  |    val1
     2323  |    val2
     8661  |    val3
     8662  |    val4
```

The view joins the tables to display the keyword values, but I'm not sure how to handle the multi-keyword field (looking to format the result like below).

## View Table

```
    Column1 | Column2 | Column3
       val1 |    val2 | val3; val4
```

Would I need some sort of function to accomplish this or is there another way?

Comment: You should know that table 1 is in a very, very poor design. Which leads you to your current problem. The right way is to have a FK of table 1 on table 2 OR  to have an associative table between then two.

Comment: Not sure why you created a such a column, but I think you have to write a function that split the column by delimiter and then deal with it

Comment: Jorge - Well, let me correct myself: Table 1 is a view from other tables that are set up like Table 2 in my example. I wanted the fields laid out horizontally so there's one row of question fields per section. The final view table will be used within Crystal Reports.

huMpty - This DB wasn't create by me, just a canned product I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using some of SQL Server's XML features ..sorry the column and table names make this kind of difficult to read, here's a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d66e1/3/0):

```
with mapped (c1, c2, val) as ( 
    select t1.column1, t1.column2, t2.column2
    from table1 t1
    cross apply (select convert(xml, '<_' + replace(substring(column3,2,len(column3)-2), '¹', '/><_') + '/>')) s(c)
    cross apply c.nodes('*') x(n)
    join table2 t2 on t2.column1=n.value('fn:substring(local-name(.),2)', 'int'))

select
    column1 = c1.column2,
    column2 = c2.column2,
    column3 = (select val + '; ' from mapped where c1=t1.column1 and c2=t1.column2 for xml path(''))
from table1 t1
join table2 c1 on c1.column1=t1.column1
join table2 c2 on c2.column1=t1.column2
```